# Java ask String input with multiple words

Tags: java

HI I am having problem with asking Direct Whole name using Java.

```
System.out.println("DOCTOR");
System.out.println("Enter ID Number:");
idnumber = scan.next();
System.out.println("Enter Name");
name = scan.next();
System.out.println("Enter Field of Specialization:");
field = scan.next();

System.out.println("ID               " + idnumber);
System.out.println("Name             " + name);
System.out.println("Specializtion    " + field );
```

and When I enter this information below:

> ID = 100  Name = Brandon Sullano

it gives me this result

```
ID               100    
Name             Brandon    
Specializtion    Sullano
```

I want Name to be dynamic so I can Input even two words how to do it?
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for Scanners methods?

Comment: I search code but I cant find will look on that documentation

Comment: Try oracles documentation. Like or oracles website. Or like, use the google

Comment: But do you know how to do it? I saw instead of scan.next will use scan.nextLine() but doesn't work

Comment: Explain "does not work." Here at SO, we are a little touchy about that phrase.

Comment: @BrandonJakeSullano next reads up to next whitespace, nextLine reads up to the next newline character. In this case, use nextLine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DoctorDoctor {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        int idnumber;
        String name, field;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("DOCTOR");

        /** Assuming ID number is an integer value */
        System.out.print("Enter ID Number: ");
        idnumber = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine(); // This is important, for clearing the new line character

        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        name = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter Field of Specialization: ");
        field = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%-15s: %d%n", "ID Number", idnumber);
        System.out.printf("%-15s: %s%n", "Name", name);
        System.out.printf("%-15s: %s%n", "Specialization", field);

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Example input/output:

```
DOCTOR
Enter ID Number: 100
Enter Name: Brandon
Enter Field of Specialization: Heart Surgeon

ID Number      : 100
Name           : Brandon
Specialization : Heart Surgeon
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
name = scan.nextLine();
```

Also, if the ID number is an integer, use `nextInt()` (make sure to also declare `idnumber` as an `int` instead of `string`)

Fixed code:

```
System.out.println("DOCTOR");
System.out.println("Enter ID Number:");
idnumber = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter Name");
name = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Field of Specialization:");
field = scan.nextLine();

System.out.println("ID               " + idnumber);
System.out.println("Name             " + name);
System.out.println("Specializtion    " + field );
```

> Using just `next()` will take all input before a space. `nextLine()` will take all input before return is pressed.

More on `Scanner` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

**Pro tip:** In most cases you'll use `scan.nextLine()` rather than `scan.next()` so you may want to get into the habit of using it.

Comment: it doesn't work  when I run System will jump asking me for Name and skip the Id number

Comment: Works fine on my end.

Comment: it will ask directly to Name and skip the ID number

Comment: @UnknownOctopus **Pro tip:** `idnumber = scan.nextInt();` needs to have a `scan.nextLine()` after it. Else, `name = scan.nextLine();` will consume the new line character, causing the program to jump to "Enter field of.."

Comment: @Watermel0n Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say `scan.nextLine()` "doesn't work", I suggest using `BufferedReader`.

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in);
//in your code:
int idnumber = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
String name = br.readLine();
String field = br.readLine();
```

You have to import `java.io.BufferedReader` and `java.io.InputStreamReader`